# Cursor becomes invisible Kubuntu 20.04 when watching videos

Tags: kubuntu, cursor

Kubuntu 20.04, KDE Plasma Version 5.18.5, KDE Frameworks Version 5.68.0, Qt Version 5.12.8, Kernel Version 5.8.0-59-generic, 64 bit, 2x Intel@Core Duo CPU E7600 @ 3.06 GHz with 3.8 GiB RAM.

Everything works great except after a few minutes of video streaming the cursor becomes invisible...

Any suggestions?

EDIT

I apologize for the ambiguity. The cursor does not just disappear over the video, it disappears permanently for all apps. The only way to get the cursor back is to reboot. I can still use the cursor and click things, I just can't see it.

Examples of video streaming that triggers the invisible cursor permanently and for all apps: Netflix and Youtube.

Comment: You didn't tell us what app you are using but this is deliberate behavior on most media players so that the cursor is not overlayed on top of the video that you are watching.

Comment: I agree completely with Nmath; it's intended behavior for some apps (which is both useful most of the time, but annoys me on occasion too). The easiest work-around is to use a different player that doesn't do it when you want to watch a video but not lose cursor, though I've also worked out ways that I can make cursor re-appear & stay visible (eg. making another window active take control.. but it's app/usage specific and you have provided no specific details as to apps)

Comment: I just clarified my question.